# Как получить key из InputText?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3, pysimplegui

Решил попробовать PySimpleGUI, но столкнулся с проблемой получения ключа из InputText. Подскажите пожалуйста, как его получить. Код прилагается:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import sqlite3
class DB:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute(
            '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student
            (id integer primary key, fa text, im text, ot text)''')
        self.conn.commit()

    def insert(fa,im,ot):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(
            '''INSERT INTO student (fa,im,ot)
            VALUES (?,?,?)''',
        (fa,im,ot))
        conn.commit()

sg.theme('Topanga')

layout =[[sg.Text('Фамилия:', size=(30,1),justification='right'),sg.InputText(key='-FAM-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text('Имя:', size=(30,1),justification='right'),sg.InputText(key='-NAME-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text('Отчество:', size=(30,1),justification= 'right'),sg.InputText(key='-OT-', do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Submit('Запись'),sg.Cancel('Отмена')]]
window = sg.Window('Форма ввода').Layout(layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    print(event,values)
    if event is None:
        break
    if event == 'Запись': #Здесь надо получить ключ и с помощью класса DB добавить в базу данных
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае, values будет словарём. И чтобы обратиться к его содержимому, нужно использовать ключи: '-FAM-', '-NAME-', '-OT-'

```
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None:
        break
    if event == 'Запись':
        print('ФАМИЛИЯ:',values['-FAM-'])
        print('ИМЯ:',values['-NAME-'])
        print('ОТЧЕСТВО:',values['-OT-'])
```